# Variable works outside if statement and not inside it

Tags: php, if-statement, variables

I managed to get variable that I would like to use for further processing. Unfortunately, I can't use it inside that if statement. Can someone tell me why?

```
$location = " ";
$persons = " ";
if (isset($_GET['filter'])) {
    $_SESSION['filter'] = "start";
    $location = $_GET['destination'];
    $checkin = $_GET['checkin'];
    $checkout = $_GET['checkout'];
    $adults = $_GET['adults'];
    $children = $_GET['children'];

    $persons = $adults + $children;

    $query = "SELECT * FROM hotels WHERE location LIKE '$location%' AND persons >= $persons";
    $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);
}
echo $location; // Working
if (isset($_SESSION['filter']) && (isset($_GET['highest']))) {
    echo $location; // Not working
    echo "example"; // Working
}
```

Comment: You are wide open for SQL injection. Since you're using mysqli, take advantage of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). **This will take care of any pesky quoting issues that may occur.**

Comment: Could you provide var_dump($_GET);

Comment: "not working" and "can't use is" are not precise descriptions of the problem you are experiencing. Can you be more specific? Also: Because you use `echo $location;` twice, how can you distinguish between them?

Comment: var_dump($_GET) - array(1) { ["highest"]=> string(3) "'1'" }  And var_dump($location) is string(1) " "

Comment: Your argument $_GET['filter'] not exist.

Comment: $_GET['filter'] is  name of submit button HTML form. Everything working corectly... Only $location doesnt work in secend If-statment

Comment: If `var_dump($_GET)` only shows `$highest`, then it's not getting all of the form data. Are you submitting the form via GET or POST? If POST, then the variables would be in `$_POST`. Otherwise, you're going to have to show your form.

Comment: Sorry.. var_dump($_GET) after submiting form shows:<br/>`array(6) { ["destination"]=> string(6) "Turkey" ["checkin"]=> string(0) "" ["checkout"]=> string(0) "" ["adults"]=> string(1) "1" ["children"]=> string(1) "0" ["filter"]=> string(6) "SEARCH" }`<br/><br/> And the query works.. Now I want to do "sort by" and I need to take `$location` to this second if-statment

Answer (score 1):

Probably the second IF conditions are not met, which could be because the $_GET['highest'] is not set.

Additionally: Please be aware that using mysqli_queries without prepared statements represents a major security vulnerability for SQL injection. This won't work for MySQLI (as @Don't Panic pointed out) but for the sake of simplicity: assume a GET request to your endpoint with a $persons variable that includes malicious SQL like:

```
1; DROP *.*;'
```

With prepared statements you tell your MySQL connection what type of variables to expect where in the SQL so that malicious SQL cannot be injected.

Comment: Not to take the side of writing vulnerable code, but your injection example can't work because `mysqli_query` will not execute multiple queries.

Comment: Right, never actually crossed over to the dark side myself. Wouldn't know if it is in any way discouraged here to design them anyway. Edited back in a reference, thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score -3):

Please try after change variable name from $location to other